# Flyway ignoring specified schema

Tags: spring, gradle, flyway, concourse

When trying to deploy my app I get this error:

```
Found non-empty schema(s) "public" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
```

Problem is that I have specified flyway to use a different schema named linked_note where the schema table history actually is. Here is my config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    tomcat:
      initSQL: ""
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:db/migration/common, db/migration/crunchy
    schemas: linked_note
    table: schema_version
```

Why is flyway ignoring the specified schema?
Why is it defaulting to public?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you already have a database in place, as well as a schema defined. In order to setup flyway for it, you need to add the following property to you configuration yaml.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/baselineOnMigrate